# Quill: How to handle keyboard events on custom blot

Tags: javascript, dom, quill

I've created custom inline-blot and want to handle keyboard events on it.

In `constructor` i wrote code like this:

```
class FooBlot extends Inline {
  constructor(domNode, value){
    super(domNode, value);
    domNode.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {this.keydown_handler(event)});
    domNode.addEventListener('click', (event) => {this.click_handler(event)});
  };
```

When i try to do something with my blot, only click event was handled, not keydown event.

You can see code example [here](https://codepen.io/szobov/pen/ZXrVzW).
Open console, click on **sometext** and you will see "clicked" in console.
But if you try to press some keyboard buttons, e.g. arrows, you will not see anything.

What the right way to handle keyboard events on my custom blot?

Comment: Please have a look at https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/

Comment: @araruna unfortunately, this module unacceptable for me, because i want use this functionality on my own custom blots. Especially, on corresponding dom-node.
I suppose, my problem has root here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6752708/6822425
https://stackoverflow.com/q/26339719/6822425
Quill's editor container use html-attribute "contenteditable", and this attr has a bit weird behavior.

Comment: Well, if you say so. But I believe that the context option, along with the fact that to every blot there is a corresponding format with the same name, would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to handle keyboard events is to use [Keyboard Module](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/)

Simple example to handle `Enter` key:

```
const bindings = {
  enter: {
    key: 13,
    shiftKey: null,
    handler: (range, context) => {
      // Handle enter
    }
  }
};

this.quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    keyboard: {
      bindings
    },
    toolbar: '#toolbar'
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

**UPDATE**

Another way:

`quill.root.addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
      // Your code goes here 
    });`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't suite in my situation. As you can notice in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620371/quill-how-to-handle-keyboard-events-on-custom-blot/51946404#comment81769938_46620371), I need a direct access to a corresponding blot, but the keyboard module give me a possibility to just handle an abstract keypress and I can't find information about on which blot it was pressed.

Comment: You can add some logic in the handler and check if it is the right blot or not.
To get a blot by index use [getLeaf](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getleaf-experimental)